Dynamics 365 plugin profile debugging causing the process to break
I have been struggling with this issue for some time:

It happens as soon as I Start execution of the profile. I don't know what's causing it and stack trace is not helpful at all. Call stack is empty, only message I get is: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module.
I can see those messages in output windows:
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'D:\tools\PluginRegistration.exe'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'D:\tools\CRMLibraries.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'D:\tools\Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'D:\tools\Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Deployment\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Deployment.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero2\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'D:\tools\Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Ui.Styles.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.Composition\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationTypes\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationTypes.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationProvider\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationProvider.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'D:\tools\PluginCommonControls.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'D:\tools\Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'D:\tools\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'D:\tools\Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'D:\tools\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemCore.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Channels\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Channels.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel.Selectors\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.Selectors.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'D:\tools\Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Services.Client\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Services.Client.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'D:\tools\PluginProfiler.Library.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'D:\tools\PluginProfiler.Plugins.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsFormsIntegration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsFormsIntegration.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'D:\tools\WPFToolkit.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemData.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'D:\tools\DebugPlugin.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'd:\visual studio\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\xamldiagnostics\Framework\x64\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.dll'. 
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (17528) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities.DurableInstancing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.DurableInstancing.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'D:\tools\Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 3): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Plug-in Domain): Loaded 'D:\tools\PluginProfiler.Library.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Plug-in Domain): Loaded 'D:\tools\PluginProfiler.Plugins.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Plug-in Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Plug-in Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Plug-in Domain): Loaded 'D:\tools\Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Plug-in Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Plug-in Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\McAfee\Endpoint Security\Adaptive Threat Protection\ATPDetectAmsiInitFail.dll'. 
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (2528) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Plug-in Domain): Loaded 'SB.Actions'. Symbols loaded.
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Plug-in Domain): Loaded 'D:\tools\Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Plug-in Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Plug-in Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'. 
'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Plug-in Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. 
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.SecurityException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.SecurityException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.SecurityException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.SecurityException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.SecurityException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.SecurityException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.SecurityException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.SecurityException' in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module.

The program '[12624] PluginRegistration.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)

.
I had the same issue with VS2019, I removed it and tried to do the same with vs2022 no luck here as well.
Have you had such issue before ? Do you know what might be the problem ?

Do you see any debug message in the VS output window?

@raygan Yes, I can see the message, I have updated the question. I can't paste it in here.

A time-consuming way to debug: Remove all your add-in code. Ensure no crash. Add code back again line by line, and debug step by step until the crash reappears.

@DouXu-MSFT What do you mean by add-in code ?

I saw this line in your output: 'PluginRegistration.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: PluginRegistration.exe): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\McAfee\Endpoint Security\Adaptive Threat Protection\ATPDetectAmsiInitFail.dll'.  Would security limit be the reason?

Sorry for spelling mistakes. I mean add-ins code(your code in this app) .Try to keep the code for the smallest unit that can be debugged normally. Then add your code line by line to see which cased the issue.

@raygan that's a nice observation, I will investigate it and get back to you.

@DouXu-MSFT I'm on it, will let you know the results

@raygan You are correct, it's related to security, Trellix's Adaptive threat protection caused this.

Hi @magicalKhachapuri, glad to hear that you found the root cause of the issue. You can share your solution, it could help other community members who get the same issues issue to find the solution easily.
